# How does one access the options for a GoogleCharts chart in the browser console?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have been looking at the Google Charts documentation and I'm confused at where I am supposed to specify certain options. For example `candlestick.fallingColor.stroke`.

With other libraries, even huge ones like Babylon.js, I have been able to comb through objects in the console and see where settings live. But, after a long time searching, I can't actually find the chart I have made, and thus the options that are available in the browser console.

I found a section called `window.google.visualization.CandlestickChart`, which matches the chart type I am using, but this appears to just be something like a prototype, as there are no key value pairs in there, but a bunch of unreadable references: `ƒ gvjs_tQ(a){gvjs_iL.call(this,a);this.cc(gvjs_d,gvjs_Ft,gvjs_S)}`

Does anyone know how I can get to my chart in the console and start poking through options?

Edit: A random chart can be found [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/kf7d8Lnt/) if that helps

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example to start with?

Comment: Link now added to a JSFiddle.

Comment: It seems to be obfuscated, I couldn't find anything useful in the console. I would refer to the documentation instead.

Comment: You can customize certain properties in the `options` object. As seen in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/0nz3b6kd/).

Comment: Thanks for looking in the console. I thought I'd tried setting the option in the format of your example, but perhaps I had muddled up the level I had put the options in at or something. That works, so I'll persevere with the docs.